# Login screen not ubuntu's; it's Gnome's

Tags: login, 15.04

I am using ubuntu 15.04 now. For a while I used Gnome as my desktop, but now I changed it back to Ubuntu. After the change, the desktop is fine, but the **login GUI** isn't back; it's still in Gnome now.

For Gnome login GUI I mean the black GUI with a gray box in the middle and there's a **gear icon**(settings of the desktop, and the options are: metacity, Gnome, System default, and Ubuntu) and some text(I cant remember that).

And the Ubuntu login GUI should be like several users appear on the left and the selected one with the text box for you to enter the password.

It is so confusing because when I lock the computer using  <kbd>Win</kbd>  +  <kbd>L</kbd> , or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>L</kbd> , the GUI is ubuntu's.

Please tell me how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to restore the Login GUI where the selected user's wallpaper apears in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- Reconfigure LightDM

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  and select <kbd>lightdm</kbd> from the list
- Uninstall GDM (GNOME Display Manager)

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge gdm
  ```

What solution do you want to use depends on you. The first command only changes the configuration of your system. Both LoginManager remain installed.

The second command removes the GNOME Login Manager completely from your system.

---

From `man dpkg-reconfigure`

```
DESCRIPTION
    dpkg-reconfigure reconfigures packages after they have already been
    installed. Pass it the names of a package or packages to reconfigure.
    It will ask configuration questions, much like when the package was
    first installed.
```

From `man apt-get`

```
purge
    purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
    purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
```

Comment: Which is recommended?

Comment: @Tim Good question, updated. :)

Comment: What does the `purge` command does?

Comment: As I said in my answer: "The second command removes the GNOME Login Manager completely from your system."

Comment: Thanks very much! It works just fine! But the GUI looks unfamiliar now, and the sound is back.

Comment: This should be a new question. :)